# The last time window popped out overrides those earlier in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Not sure My title is correct or not actually.

I have a button, when I click on it, it will pop up a small window (based on data in a repeater) to let the user key-in information and click the `OK` button to proceed to next step.

Below is my code of the `Button.Click` :

```
protected void btnRedeemAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
foreach( RepeaterItem itm in repGiftResults.Items )
{
    if (pr.AdditionalFieldsEnabled == true)
    {
        AdditionalInfoGiftProcess(pid, giftId, txtQty, txtToken);
    }
}
}
```

divAdditionalInfo is a division ID, divAdditionalInfo.Style["visibility"] = "visible"; and divAdditionalInfo.Style["display"] = "table-cell"; is to prompt out a window to let user key in information and click on "OK" button to continue :
The following the the code of AdditionalInfoGiftProcess() function :

```
public void AdditionalInfoGiftProcess(int productID, int giftID, TextBox txtQty, UserControls_TokenControl txtToken)
{
    /*
    Some logic here
    */

    //generate pop up window
    divAdditionalInfo.Style["visibility"] = "visible";
    divAdditionalInfo.Style["display"] = "table-cell";
}
```

And below is my code of `divAdditionalInfo` in html :

```
<div 
    id="divAdditionalInfo" 
    class="BlackCover" 
    style="VISIBILITY:hidden; DISPLAY:none;" runat="server">
<!-- 
    html code that generate the pop out window. 
    consist of text box and `OK` button, and "Cancel" button. 
-->
</div>
```

When I click on `temoBtn` button, I only get 1 time window(div) pop out, means I only can enter 1 time information and click on `OK` button.

I want the window(div) to **pop out 3 times one by one**, so that I can key in information for 3 times and click on the `OK` button 1 by 1.

But, the last time window pop out seen like already override those early pop out window.

Any idea to solve this?

p.s.: Actually you can ignore the html code. It is just a code to generate the pop out window. Means, when I click on `tempBtn` button, the division with `id = "divAdditionalInfo"` will prompt out as a window to let the user to key-in info and click on the `OK` button.

Comment: Hi Ken Kin, actually you can ignore the html code. It is just a code to generate the pop out window. Means, when I click on tempBtn button, the division with id = "divAdditionalInfo" will prompt out as a window to let user key in info and click on OK button.

Comment: If it's considered ignorable, then it would be the weak message here, which may increase the difficulty for people who want to help you.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, I am new to Stack Over Flow. I will edit my question.

Comment: Done edit. Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Look like no one look on this. Should I re post this question?

Comment: No. I guess the original html scaring people .. But be patient, if some understand the question and felt who can help, they will.

Comment: Why have three popups? Why not have one popup with all the required information? and validate that information / give out error messages as necessary.

Comment: Hi Paul Zahra, actually, I already simplify the actual code. 
Actually the for loop is edit based on a repeater. I have a repeater, and inside the repeater, if meet my condition, then it will call function which is do pop out window, of course, everytime the element in pop out window will be different, so I can key in different info in the window and click on OK button. So I can not make it in 1 pop up. Let me know if my question is not clear : )
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to happen here? When the user clicks OK, should anything happen? Or does the user need to click OK three times in order for the popup to go away?

In any case - as your code stands now, the server is generating a div that is visible. Making it visible once has the same effect as making it visible three times. Once you're by the client, you can try to use JavaScript to force the user to work with the div three times before it will go away.

This doesn't sound like a good situation for the user; maybe consider using separate elements for your three popups?

EDIT:

I'm still not sure how you are setting the style of different elements with your code. Where is the div declared? Inside the template of a repeater? If so - I'm surprised that your code compiles. You would need to loop through the generated template instances of your repeater and call `FindControl("divAdditionalInfo")` on each of them to get access to each instance of the div.

Comment: actually, I already simplify the actual code. Actually the for loop is edit based on a repeater. I have a repeater, and inside the repeater, if meet my condition, then it will call function which is do pop out window, of course, everytime the element in pop out window will be different, so I can key in different info in the window and click on OK button. So I can not make it in 1 pop up. Let me know if my question is not clear : ) Thanks.

Comment: I don't think anyone here will be able to help you with the question as it stands; why not post your actual code, or something more similar to it?

Comment: @PanadolChong: I think the question is in fact nothing about *function override* of the language, but **the later popped up window overrides earlier**.

Comment: Hi Ken Kin, I am new to Stack Over Flow, would like to ask, how to approve your edit?

Comment: ya, I also thinking that your edited title is more suitable, but I do not know how to approve your edit..

Comment: @PanadolChong: Just make the title matches its content.

Comment: @sq33G , already edit my code. hope you can help me have a look again. Let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: @sq33G , the div is declare in default.ascx, not inside repeater. In the default.ascx,  I have `<asp:Panel> </asp:Panel>`, then follow by this `<div id="divAdditionalInfo"></div>` . The repeater is inside the `<asp:panel>` , the repeater is use to display data in browser by getting those data from database. I no need to use `findControl()` to get access to each instance of the division. This division is just use to be the pop up window. Inside the repeater, when the row of data inside the repeater meet the condition `(pr.AdditionalFieldsEnabled == true)` , then call AdditionalGiftProcess().

Comment: Let me know if my statement make you blur. I am new to programming and C# , and maybe what I write is not professional.

Comment: How exactly do you expect to render three div elements to HTML when you have only one div element declared?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything to accept input, in your loop.

All you are doing is setting the visibility 3 times, then moving on.

In your handler for the OK and cancel buttons, you could check for any pending messages and show the next one, if necessary.

Comment: Actually in the pop up window, i have do validation on user input. The text box field inside the pop up window is not allow blank. Means, when the last window pop up, I must key in something in the text box field can click on "OK" button, else, will prompt error message. But I facing problem that all those earlier pop up window just gone, no chance to fill in those data.

Comment: You only have one divAdditionalInfo.  It can only do once thing at once.  Since you don't have anything waiting for user input, your loop keeps going, and only the last iteration has any effect.

Comment: Means that those text box that I create in divAdditonalInfo not consider as thing that waiting for user input?

Comment: Your backend code can't wait for the user's input from the browser.  It does all of its work, then sends the updated web page to the user.

Comment: Is there any way to make the backend code to wait for user's input from the browser?

Comment: Look back at my original answer.  You would show the first dialog where you have your loop now.  Then in your OK/Cancel handler you would show the next dialog.  Repeat until you have all of your values.